# How do I printout a variable from class1 written in class2 in javascript?

Tags: java

So I'm doing a a saleproject and it prints out what you pay and your change, but I have another class in the same project which displays time, if I want to print out my prices from class1 but I want the time to also be included from class 2 when I print it out? help.
I'm using system.out.print1ln btw

Comment: I can't share my code for reasons, but like I explained there's 2 classes  1 for clock which has variable hour minutes and seconds, and the other one just basically allows you to insert money into machine and buy something and if you have enough money in the machine you can buy the item then the system prints out what you bought with your change but I want the printing system to display timer so how do I import my time from class2 into class1 when I use the print in feature from class1

Comment: I'm using bluej? sorry I didn't mention that, can I contact you privately maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You want the current time and date right then this might do :

```
   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(" HH:mm:ss");
   //get current date time with Date()
   Date date = new Date();
   System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

After that just when you make a customer object declare an attribute than carries its time with it and store the time within that field or more precisely within that string.

Comment: Thanks but now I can't add questions to this site I just joined and it's telling me I'm blocked :/  I only have 2 questions up

Comment: @PedramCarter ["What can I do when getting 'we are no longer accepting questions / answers from this account'"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: It doesn't make sense I did nothing wrong, in my understanding I need to contribute to the community, I assume answering questions, do I have to? can't I just ask questions only?

Comment: Well no its a free world more like a web :p 
I don't quite get why you got blocked or so, must have been something sever but what so ever did you got your answer ?